# How to show that a gradient is a sum of gradients?

Tags: neural-networks

I am learning about neural networks and specially back propagation.

How can one show in case a neural network appears more than once that the gradient of the loss function according to this weight matrix is a sum of two gradients?
For an example, please refer to [example 3](http://ufldl.stanford.edu/wiki/index.php/Deriving_gradients_using_the_backpropagation_idea).

Comment: Because $\nabla$ is a linear operator?

Comment: Can you elaborate more? My maths skills are a bit rusty now

Comment: Do you believe derivatives are a linear operation? Yes? Good.